# MYSQL select sum for existing dates and 0 for future dates

Tags: mysql

I have been able to select all of the months with values from this year and last if they exist. What I am trying to do is create a future date if nothing exists for it yet with a TotalAmount of 0. I could possibly fill this in using PHP however I am hoping MYSQL will have a simpler solution.

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y'), '%m-%Y') AS Date_Month,
SUM(Invoice.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM Invoice
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND NOW()
GROUP BY Date_Month
ORDER BY Date_Month
```

Current Output:

```
01-2016 | 103077
01-2017 | 104925
02-2016 | 187065
02-2017 | 32865
03-2016 | 135525
04-2016 | 106500
05-2016 | 98812
06-2016 | 111690
07-2016 | 96193
08-2016 | 123970
09-2016 | 126356
10-2016 | 147454
11-2016 | 160254
12-2016 | 98430
```

Expected Output:

```
01-2016 | 103077
01-2017 | 104925
02-2016 | 187065
02-2017 | 32865
03-2016 | 135525
03-2017 | 0
04-2016 | 106500
04-2017 | 0
05-2016 | 98812
05-2017 | 0
06-2016 | 111690
06-2017 | 0
07-2016 | 96193
07-2017 | 0
08-2016 | 123970
08-2017 | 0
09-2016 | 126356
09-2017 | 0
10-2016 | 147454
10-2017 | 0
11-2016 | 160254
11-2017 | 0
12-2016 | 98430
12-2017 | 0
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings?

Comment: It's parsed out of long text documents

Comment: Store dates as dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a query like this, but is not tested

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y'), '%m-%Y') AS Date_Month,
SUM(IF(STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date > NOW(), 0, Invoice.Amount)) AS TotalAmount
FROM Invoice
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Invoice.Date, '%m/%e/%Y') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AND NOW()
GROUP BY Date_Month
ORDER BY Date_Month;
```